# Ruby on rails.Generating controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why when I write `rails generate controller home index` the index.html.erb file is not created in the views folder? And when I run `rails server` and want to watch http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/index terminal output.

> Started GET "/home/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-01-10 01:54:30 +0200
> Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
> Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 60)

Comment: Well, what does get created when you run that? This might help you get it worked out to what you need https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-generate

Answer (score 1):

When I check error log I see `HomeController#index`, I would like you to check `rails routes` first. You should see a result similar to this:

```
Prefix      Verb   URI Pattern            Controller#Action

home_index  GET    /home/index(.:format)  home#index
...
```

If you are seeing `homecontroller#index` instead of `home#index` you can access by going to related URI pattern.

You can control which files are created when you run `rails generate` command. This is a sample output:

```
➜ rails g controller home index    
Running via Spring preloader in process 1934
      create  app/controllers/home_controller.rb
       route  get 'home/index'
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/home
      create    app/views/home/index.html.erb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/home_helper.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/home.scss
```

As you see there is a file `app/views/home/index.html.erb` make sure that it is not empty. For example put `<p>Home</p>` in this file, if it is empty.

I hope it is clear enough and I think this will solve your problem.